# Which design pattern to use in order to implement "data extenders"?

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class DataBuilder {
  public DataBlock create() {
    DataBlock block = new DataBlock();
    for (Extender extender : this.getExtenders()) {
      extender.extend(block);
    }
  }
}
```

Some time later:

```
DataBlock block = new DataBuilder().create();
```

Every `extender` will add some specific information to the `block`. `DataBuilder` doesn't want to know anything about internal structure of these extenders. Currently my `getExtenders()` method finds all subclasses of `Extender` (in classpath), and returns instances of them.

Works fine, but I don't like how it looks, in terms of design. Maybe I could/should use some pattern, to make this construct more flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing Adrian's answer, I'll explain briefly how it would work:

Lets suppose DataBlock derives from an interface called IDataBlock. Each extender derives from DataBlockDecorator which derives from IDataBlock which does some operation to the DataBlock (accepting IDataBlock in the constructor).  This allows you to do something like.

```
IDataBlock block = new DataBlock();
for (DataBlockDecorator extender : this.getExtenders()) {
  extender.extend(block);
  block = extender;
}
```

However, it doesn't really add anymore flexibility than before.  For that matter, your original solution is already as flexible as it gets.

Comment: The trick is with `this.getExtenders()`, which is not as flexible as it should be. The rest is the same, and Decorator pattern just makes things more complicated... As I see it. Right?

Comment: @Vincenzo: You are missing a small, but significant detail. As long as your extenders do not actually extend anything, but perform just a one-time change of the object, you are right. However, if your extender is to extend the object whenever a call to the real object is performed (think of a wrapper), the decorator pattern is the right approach because it adds more flexibility.

Comment: @Vincenzo Ah, I think I see where you're getting at.  Unfortunately to instantiate many classes, you're either going to have to specify their names in some sense or use a reflection tactic like the one you employed.  Best you can hope for is to encapsulate this loading into some sort of Factory and perhaps attempt to instantiate all classes which implement some interface (rather than a physical class).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Could you please give a short example how Decorator will work in my case?

Comment: @Vincenzo If I understand your OP correctly, you are looking for a pattern to add or edit the behavior of a block without embedding any knowledge about the inner workings of the extender into the builder. The extender therefore is a decorator for your block. Have a look at the wikipedia site above for an in-depth explanation and several examples on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator Pattern

```
interface BlockDeckorator
{
    extend(DataBlock block);
}

class FooBlockDecoratorImpl implements BlockDecorator
{
    private BlockDeckorator blockDecorator;

    public FooBlockDecoratorImpl(BlockDecorator decorator)
    {
         this.blockDecorator = decorator;
    }

    public void extend(DataBlock block)
    {
         blockDecorator(block);
         // Add my own code to do Foo afterwards (or before)
    }
}
```